# Having an issue using the audioplayers package for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Im creating a flutter app that requires a user to complete certain tasks in order to stop an alarm clock. Its a more imersive alarm clock app that could help stimulate the brain in order to aid in the process of waking up.

Im having some issues working with the hardware for the application, so to simulate an alarm going off im trying to use the audioplayers package to play an mp3 file once a button is pressed. Im aware that in order to use a local mp3 file I must utilize audio_cache with audioplayers.

when trying to import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart'; I recive this error

"Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart'. Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist"

Im also having trouble putting the local mp3 file that I want into my pubspec.yaml. The readMe for audio cache states that I have to place the file in my assest folder and specify the file path in my pubspec under assets. However I do not see an assets folder. I created a file named assets and placed the mp3 in there, but I dont belive this is what I was supposed to do. I also belive that I am placing the file path into my pubspec wrong as well.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Time Attack',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: const Text('Time Attack'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final player = AudioCache();
            //bool isPLaying = false;
            player.play('musicForapp.mp3');
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          child: const Icon(Icons.punch_clock),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(170),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: const Text(
                  "Click the Icon in the bottem left to simulate an alarm",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => const TasksPage(),
                    ),
                  );
                }, //on pressed
                child: const Text(
                  "Navigate",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } //widget build
}

class TasksPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TasksPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TasksPage> createState() => _TasksPageState();
}

class _TasksPageState extends State<TasksPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: const Text('Tasks'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => const MyHomePage(),
                    ),
                  );
                }, //on pressed
                child: const Text(
                  "Navigate",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } //widget build
}
```

Here is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: timeattack2
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.2 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  audioplayers: ^1.1.1


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    -assets/musicForapp.mp3

  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

All in all Here are my issues:

1.) issue importing audio cache package for code

2.) placing the mp3 file in the correct "assest" folder

3.) Specifiying the file path in pubspec.yaml as to where my mp3 file is

Comment: Kindly add a screenshot of your folder structure

Answer (score 0):

Remove cache import section and try this way

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  AudioPlayer p = AudioPlayer();
  await p.play(AssetSource('assets/musicForapp.mp3'));
},
```

And yaml

```yaml
  assets:
    - assets/musicForapp.mp3
```

Comment: ok i will try that, does the pubspec look ok then?

Comment: there will a space like ` assets:
    - assets/musicForapp.mp3`

Comment: im reciving the error 
The asset file 'assets/musicForapp.mp3' doesn't exist.
Try creating the file or fixing the path to the file

Comment: comment cache section &  try `await p.play(AssetSource('assets/musicForapp.mp3'));`

Comment: That error was in my pubspec file when adding  assets: - assets/musicForapp.mp3 to the file

Comment: try direct play also are you creating `assets` directory and putting on that music file. make sure to rebuild the app